# SanDisk MobileMate USB 3.0 Reader (0781:cfcb SDDR-B531) not detected in Ubuntu 20.04.1 (amd)

Tags: drivers, usb, sd-card

I am able to use Transcend and Anker microSD card readers without any problems, however the SanDisk MobileMate USB 3.0 Reader is not being detected by lsblk.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on ODROID-H2+ (x86-64).

The microSD card I am using is SanDisk Extreme Pro microSDXC UHS-1 (64GB).
It works fine in the Anker card reader.

```
$ lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core18/1880
loop1       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core18/1885
loop2       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop3       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop4       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/snap-store/415
loop5       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop6       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/snap-store/481
loop7       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/snapd/9607
loop8       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop10      squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/snapd/9721
sda                                                                            
└─sda1      btrfs    btrfs 9b446950-54ca-47e9-8222-e9195eb1bcba    621G    33% /media/btrfs
sdb                                                                            
└─sdb1      btrfs    esg1  cee327a8-f8f2-41b2-82f0-29dca06f9783    8.6T     5% /media/esg
nvme0n1                                                                        
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat           05FE-A040                             503.2M     2% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 ext4           979af009-fc22-4d84-82ce-546ecef53037   68.9G    63% /
├─nvme0n1p3 ext4           eb076189-7e85-4c27-bf1a-43ada157b088                
└─nvme0n1p4 swap           0817cf3d-0e73-4a83-b376-6d9d28e64c0f
```

I've tried unplugging it and plugging back in.

I've tried removing other USB devices and changing the USB 3.0 port that I was using.

I do notice that the card reader seems to be warmer than expected. I'm guessing that might have to do with its much smaller size?

I've tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks2
$ sudo reboot
```

lsusb reveals this ...

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0781:cfcb SanDisk Corp. SDDR-B531
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:0833 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd KU-0833 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:0939 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and

```
$ find /dev/bus
/dev/bus
/dev/bus/usb
/dev/bus/usb/002
/dev/bus/usb/002/002
/dev/bus/usb/002/001
/dev/bus/usb/001
/dev/bus/usb/001/003
/dev/bus/usb/001/002
/dev/bus/usb/001/001
```

and

```
$ lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/002/002
Device: ID 0781:cfcb SanDisk Corp. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x0781 SanDisk Corp.
  idProduct          0xcfcb 
  bcdDevice           29.20
  iManufacturer           3 
  iProduct                4 
  iSerial                 2 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x002c
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              896mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               4
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try installing openct, I installed it from AUR repo on Manjaro (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/openct), on Ubuntu you can try to build it manually after downloading the code from Github (https://github.com/OpenSC/openct). I got my SanDisk sdcard reader working. The output from lsusb is:

```
~$ sudo lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/002/006

Device: ID 0781:cfcb SanDisk Corp. SDDR-B531
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x0781 SanDisk Corp.
  idProduct          0xcfcb 
  bcdDevice           29.20
  iManufacturer           3 SanDisk
  iProduct                4 SDDR-B531
  iSerial                 2 0401220000021620
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x002c
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              896mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               4
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               4
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x0016
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000f0e
      BESL Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
    BESL value     3840 us 
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat        2047 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x000c
  (Bus Powered)
  U1 Enabled
  U2 Enabled
```